# Laravel Guzzle parsing

Tags: php, json, laravel, parsing, guzzle

I am communicating with external API with Guzzle and fetching a response in this manner:

`return $res->getBody()->getContents();`

This part works fine, and I can see in Chrome inspector values returned. The issue I'm facing is fetching a specific value in the response. I have nested JSON with 3 values: `aggregations` (array of values), `hits` (array of values), `total` (number). I don't want to return everything, I just want to return values under `hits`.

`$res->hits` doesn't work

`$res['hits']` doesn't work

`json_encode($res)` just returns an ugly long string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $res->getBody()->getContents();
return json_decode($data)->hits;
```